# video is not getting rendered on safari browser and ios devices from web service api

Tags: django, web-services, azure, nginx, safari

**software configuration**
django : web api services
angular2 : web app [frontend]
Ionic1  : mobile [ ios and android ]
MongoDB : database
Azure blob storage : for storing images and videos

**Environment configuration :**

- Django web services deployed on Ubuntu VM  [ on azure platform behind loadbalancer ]
- Application server : gunicorn version 19.7.1
- Proxy web server : Nginx version 1.12.2

**details**

1. I am working on web application kind of blogs. Blog contents are displayed from web api services
2. for single Blog, contents are retrieved by calling single service which returns Json data, Which contains  urls of web api video rendering service. 
   for ex:
   `{data :[{"description ":"this is video1","url":"domain/videorender/v1.mp4"},{"description ":"this is video2","url":"domain/videorender/v2.mp4"}]}`
3. So when blog is accessed, respective web service will called as defined in "url" field
4. When url is accessed, django web service method internally retrieve video from azure blob and return HttpStreaming response.
5. Videos are getting rendered on on webapp on all browsers[ except safari], android [all devices], ios [None]

**Troubleshooting**

1. Tried different video formats : **Not working**
2. Tried accessing video files directly stored on VM instead of accessing from azure blob  [ Just to verify problem in blob to streaming reponse ] : **Not working**

   3. Tried changing nginx configuration as suggested in different posts : **Not Working**
   4. I even tried directly accessing web service url in safari browser from json response : **Not working**

I don't know whether issue is with nginx configuration or with safari browser. 
I have tried all the possible options and totally stuck.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: When you try to test this port, does it work? What is the result `netstat -ant|grep <port>`?

Comment: @ShengbaoShui-MSFT i did netstat -ant|grep 443   tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:443             0.0.0.0:*                            LISTEN
.    .  .   .                                 TIME_WAIT
.    .  .   .                                 TIME_WAIT
.    .  .   .                                 TIME_WAIT
tcp        0      0 10.2.0.1:44688         55.116.222.28:443       TIME_WAIT
tcp        0      0 10.2.0.1:44600         55.116.222.28:443       TIME_WAIT
tcp6       0      0 :::443                  :::*                    LISTEN

Comment: You open port 443 on Azure NSG? The service is listening on 443?

Comment: Yes. I already did. I can access all services on android, web and ios. Everything is working except video on ios.

Comment: If you test the port, could you access it?

Comment: yes. I can access.

Comment: @ShengbaoShui-MSFT I observed one thing that though 443 port on nginx is open but all requests are going port 80. I tried allowing only 443 and disabling 80 then requests are not reaching to nginx. We have used ssl certificate at loadbalancer. There is no certificate at vm. And our url  start with https. Does this  cause issue?